# ProgrressDialog frezees while AsynTask is still running when download large file

Tags: android, cordova, android-asynctask, freeze, progressdialog

I have a strangle behavior when implementing AsynTask and ProgressDialog. When i download small file, everything works fine, the progress status is updated from 0% to 100%. But when i download larger files, the number on ProgressDialog runs to 6 or 7% then it is not updated anymore. But after 2,3 minutes, i receive a messge that asyntask task finished the downloading process.

```
public class DownloadHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener{

    private volatile boolean running = true;

    private PhonegapActivity _ctx = null;
    private ProgressDialog _progressDialog = null;
    private String _title = null;
    private File _root = null;
    private File _destination = null;
    private DatabaseHelper _dbHelper = null;

    private Cursor _cursorMedia = null;

    public DownloadHelper(String title, File root, File destination, DatabaseHelper dbHelper, PhonegapActivity ctx){
        _title = title;
        _ctx = ctx;
        _root = root;
        _destination = destination;
        _dbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (_progressDialog != null)
        {
            _progressDialog.dismiss();
            _progressDialog = null;
        }
        _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_ctx);
        _progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        _progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
        _progressDialog.setMessage(_title);
        _progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        _progressDialog.setMax(100);
        _progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        /*_progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() { 
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    _progressDialog = null;
                    running = false;
                }
        });
        _progressDialog.setOnDismissListener(
            new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.d("DownloadHelper", "canceled inside listener");
                    _progressDialog = null;
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        );*/
        _progressDialog.show();

        running = true;
     }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            Log.d("DownloadHelper", "Start download from url " + sUrl[0]);
            long total = 0;
            total = _download(sUrl[0], _destination);

            return total;
        } catch (Exception ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("DownloadHelper", "Failed to download test file from " + sUrl[0] + " to " + _destination.getAbsolutePath().toString());
            _closeProgressDialog();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onCancelled(Long result) {
        Log.d("DownloadHelper", "CANCELLED result = " + result);
        _closeProgressDialog();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        if (_progressDialog != null && running)
        {
            Log.d("DownloadHelper", "UPDATED progess = " + progress[0]);
            _progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
        else //cancel the task
        {
            Log.d("DownloadHelper", "onProgressUpdate cancelled");
            cancel(true);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Log.d("DownloadHelper", "FINISHED result = " + result);

        // Close the ProgressDialog
        _closeProgressDialog();
        running = false;

        if (result != null) //OK
        {
            _showAlertDialog("Test has been downloaded successfully.", "Message", "OK");        
        }
        else // error
        {
            _showAlertDialog("Can not download the test. Please try again later.", "Error", "OK");      
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }    

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.d("DownloadHelper", "Cancelled");
        this.cancel(true);
    }


    protected void _closeProgressDialog(){
        if (_progressDialog != null)
        {
            _progressDialog.dismiss();
            _progressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    protected void _showAlertDialog(final String message, final String title, final String buttonLabel){
        AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(_ctx);
        dlg.setMessage(message);
        dlg.setTitle(title);
        dlg.setCancelable(false);
        dlg.setPositiveButton(buttonLabel,
                new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dlg.create();
        dlg.show();     
    }

    protected Cursor _checkMedia() {

        _dbHelper.openDatabase(_destination.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("DownloadHelper", "Database is opened");

        String[] columns = {"type, size, location, location_id, url"};
        Cursor cursor = _dbHelper.get("media", columns);

        _dbHelper.closeDatabase();
        _dbHelper.close();
        _dbHelper = null;

        return cursor;
    }

    protected long _download(String sUrl, File destination) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("DownloadHelper", "length of File = " + lenghthOfFile);

        // downlod the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;
        int count;

        // Reset the progress
        _progressDialog.setProgress(0);

        // Start downloading main test file
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && running) {
            total += count;
            Log.d("DownloadHelper", "total = " + total);
            // publishing the progress....
            this.publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghthOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        if (running == false)
        {
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

        return total;
    }
}
```

I also add a Log.d message inside onProgressUpdate(), the debug messages show until the progress reaches 6 or 7% then nothing comes out anymore in the console (but the app still works because i don't receive any error messages and the message of Gabrage Collector still shows in the console).

Here is my code

Does anyone have the some problems?

**Edited**

I changed the buffer size to 1MB as suggestion of DArkO, but it still doesn't work. I think something is wrong with my while loop. I use log.d inside my while loop and have some like this in console:

```
    D/DownloadHelper( 1666): length = **3763782**; total = 77356; percent = 2; save_percent = 0
    D/DownloadHelper( 1666): UPDATED progess = 2
    D/DownloadHelper( 1666): length = 3763782; total = 230320; percent = 6; save_percent = 0
    D/DownloadHelper( 1666): UPDATED progess = 6
    D/dalvikvm( 1666): GC freed 10241 objects / 1087168 bytes in 88ms
    *D/DownloadHelper( 1666): FINISHED result = **230320***
```

The "FINISHED message" comes from onPostExecute(). This message came 1,2 minutes later after the progress dialog had stopped. As you can see the file is not downloaded completely.

I debug the my app with debug tool of eclipse, i can see that the asynctask thread hangs at this function

```
OSNetworkSystem.receiveStreamImpl(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are updating it too often it cant display the updates in time and it blocks the ui thread.

consider using a handler with postDelayed to send a publishProgress update maybe every second or 2.

or alternatevely you can increase the buffer size so the loop isnt happening that often, right now you have it on 1024 bytes so maybe half a MB or something like that, but i would still go with the handler method instead. that way your updates and memory consumption doesnt depend on the progress updates.

**EDIT:**

here is the code i was using for one of my projects to download files. i have tested this with quite large files (between 50 and 100 mb) so it is definitely working. try it out.

```
try {

        // this is the file to be downloaded
        final URL url = new URL(Url); // set the download URL, a url that
        // points to a file on the internet
        // create the new connection
        final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        // set up some things on the connection and connect!
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(4500); // Connection timeout in
        // miliseconds

        urlConnection.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
        // set the path where we want to save the file
        // in this case on root directory of the
        // sd card.
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+MUSIC_VIDEOS_PATH+artist);
        // create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        // which we want to save the file as.

        directory.mkdirs(); // If we want to save the file in another
        // directory on the SD card
        // we need to make the directories if they dont exist.

        // you can download to any type of file ex: (image), (text file),
        // (audio file)
        Log.i(TAG, "File Name:" + filename);
        final File file = new File(directory, filename);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        // this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we
        // created
        final FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        // this is the total size of the file
        final int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        // variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        // a buffer
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; // used to store a temporary size of the
        // buffer
        int lastProgress = 0, progress = 0;
        // now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the
        // file
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            // add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output
            // stream (the file on the sd card
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            // add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            // this is where you would do something to report the prgress,
            // like this maybe
            // Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+String.valueOf((int)((downloadedSize/(double)totalSize)*100))+" %  totalSize:"+
            // totalSize) ;
            progress = (int) ((downloadedSize / (double) totalSize) * 100);
            if (progress != lastProgress && progress % 10 == 0) {
                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.ProgressBar01,
                        100, progress, false);
                // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
                nm.notify(id, notification);
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(progress));
            }
            lastProgress = progress;
        }
        // close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.flush();
        fileOutput.close();
```

you will notice i am using the notification's bar to do the updates instead of a progress bar but the rest should be the same.

Comment: I agree using a 1024 byte buffer is also going to be very inefficient. I would suggest allocating based on size of the file being downloaded - use `lenghthOfFile` and allocate a buffer maybe 20% or 10% of total. This would also slow down progress updates.

Comment: Or, you know, only publish updates every time `percentage` (a new variable) increases in 1.

Comment: well first about the percentage: this means he will also need to calculate the new percentage, compare it and store it-post the progress update which is also very inefficient. and about the buffer size my opinion is still that you need to go with a fixed size instead dinamically adjusting to the file size because consider the larger files (like 100 mb means allocating a 20 mb buffer which is a definite out of memory crash, 50 mb is 10mb buffer which is probably also an out of memory situation. my experience tells me that 0.5 mb to 1 mb is a great buffer size. with an expensive app even less

Comment: I have edited my response to give you a sample of what i have used before for downloading larger files. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the updates are occurring too often, but instead of a handler object to publish progress I'd probably write it something like the following with a bit of simple integer maths.

It uses a precalculated tickSize (effectively the percent of the total size you want to show progress updates), and then tracks when to show next progress with a bit of simple integer division that isn't too compute heavy (uses 2 `int`s instead of a `Handler` object).

```
int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength(); // note spelling :)
int tickSize = 2 * lengthOfFile / 100; // adjust to how often you want to update progress, this is 2%
int nextProgress = tickSize;

// ...

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && running) {
    total += count;
    if (total >= nextProgress) {
        nextProgress = (total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize;
        this.publishProgress((int)(total*100/lengthOfFile));
    }
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

// ...
```